# C# : cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' error

Tags: c#

The problem is the

```
return playerInfo[name][timetype];
```

line. And I have no idea what is wrong.

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    // scoreboard
    public class bandau : MonoBehaviour
    {
        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> playerInfo;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start()
        {
            SetName("po", "time", "0220");
            Debug.Log(GetName("po", "time"));
        }

        void Init()   // to do then its needs to be done
        {
            if (playerInfo != null)
            {
                playerInfo = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
            }
        }

        public int GetName(string name, string timetype)
        {
            Init();

            if (playerInfo.ContainsKey(name) == false)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            if (playerInfo[name].ContainsKey(timetype) == false)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            return playerInfo[name][timetype]; //Where is the problem?
        }  //function to get player name ant other parameters

        public void SetName(string name, string timetype, string value )
        {
            Init();

            if(playerInfo.ContainsKey(name) == false)
            {
                playerInfo[name] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            }

            playerInfo[name][timetype] = value;
        }   // set player values

        public void ChangeName(string name, string timetype, string amount)
        {
            Init();
            int currName = GetName(name, timetype);
            SetName(name, timetype, currName + amount);
        }  // if needs to be changed

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
        }
}
```

Comment: `GetName`'s return type is `int`. That sounds like that should be `string`.

Comment: Obviously `playerInfo[name][timetype]` is a string and you're returning it as integer return value.

Comment: Clearly `playerInfo[name][timetype]` is a `string`.  Exactly as the error tells you.

Comment: The dictionary returns a `string`, and the method returns an `int`.

Comment: I think the more pressing question is... Why do you refer to numeric values as "names"?  What you're *calling* things is causing you confusion, leading to this error (and likely others).

Answer (score 4):

`playerInfo` is of type `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>`. This means that `playerInfo[name][timetype]` will be a string.

Your method `GetName` has signature `public int GetName(string name, string timetype)` which says that it is returning an int. However at the end of that method you have `return playerInfo[name][timetype];` which means that for a method that expects you are returning an int in fact is trying to return a string. Thus the compiler tells you that it is trying to convert the string to an int but is unable to because there is no implicit conversion.